# How closing/changing the fragment with a finger swipe down?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, drag-and-drop, fragmenttransaction

There is a wonderful application **"Plaid"** (https://github.com/nickbutcher/plaid)

If you open *any image* or the *About screen*, a new ***Activity*** opens. And it can be swipe down or up and it closes.

I've found a redesigned implementation of **"Android-DragDismissActivity"** (https://github.com/klinker24/Android-DragDismissActivity), but it's all based on ***Activity***.

Tell me, how to approach the implementation of this on the **fragments**?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Before replacing the fragment you can set up an animation:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.your_anim_in, R.anim.your_anim_out);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But, how create fragment draging over other? (how example in application Plaid)